# Avoid 32bit overflow via using string

Tags: c, cs50

upd. So i've just realized it was actually pretty dumb idea, since, as far as I understand, there's no way to transform negative "overflown" number to string, unless somehow to forbid compiler show " - " before the number.

It's my first message, so please excuse if I got something wrong.
So, have got this base code from week 1 lecture.

```
int main(void)
{
    int n = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        printf("n is %i\n", n);
        n = n * 2;
    }
}
```

I've been thinking to assign string n in order to pass through -2billion.

```
int main(void)
{
    int n = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        printf("n is %i\n", n);
        n = n * 2;
        if (n < 0){
            string n = get_string();
            printf("n is %s\n", n);
        }
    }
}
```

And it gives an error: `declaration shadows a local variable`. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: I think it is not a compile error ( It's warning. Or the compilation option causes a warning to be an error.), but you can use a different name that does not duplicate.

Comment: Also I don't think that letting the user enter a string will avoid overflow.

Comment: `string n = get_string();` string is undefined here.

Comment: Actually i thought only about getting these 64 numbers but only with 64th (-2147483648) being positive instead of negative. Just to understand logic better.

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/fxc6Wg)

Comment: Oh, thanks. It's turns out to be more complicated then I expected it to be and with some yet unfamiliar to me syntax .

Answer (score 1):

You can do following to not show this warning:

- Don't use `n` twice for declaring the variable i.e. either rename `int n` or `string n` with any other name.
- Don't use `-Wshadow` switch of compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid 32 bit overflow by using a larger type: `unsigned long long` is guaranteed to have at least 64 value bits:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned long long n = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        printf("n is %llu\n", n);
        n = n * 2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know. The idea was not about avoiding 32bit overflow, but rather make it seem so. I just was curious to understand the logic better.

Comment: @Elagoff:  You could just use an unsigned type to avoid the overflow into negative values.  signed integer overflow is actually undefined behavior, whereas unsigned arithmetics is performed modulo `UINT_MAX+1`.